# TwigBridge extending base template not working

Tags: laravel, templates, twig

I used [TwigBridge](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge) because I prefer using Twig than blade. The problem is extending a base template returns an error.

> Error loading ../resources/views/main/index.twig: Template
>   "../layouts/base.index.twig" is not defined (TwigBridge\Twig\Loader:
>   View [../layouts/base.index] not found.) in
>   "../resources/views/main/index.twig"

I've tried extending the template like this and it's not working:

> {% extends '../layouts/base.index.twig' %}
>
> {% extends '../layouts/base.index' %}

Here's the resources/views structure:

[image: View Structure]

Here's the content of the view files:
base.index.twig

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bundle.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}


<script src="{{ asset('js/bundle.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the index.twig

```
{% extends '../layouts/base.index.twig' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="page-header text-center my-5"> <h1>Laravel Todo App</h1> </div>
<div class="float-right pb-3 pr-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"> Add todo </button>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Todo</th>
        <th scope="col">Description</th>
        <th scope="col">Deadline</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: remove . twig as in its https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge usage they told 
{% extends "parent" %} it work like that

Comment: already tried it, still not working.

Comment: same error ? or diffrent one because in this it can't find your file

Comment: same error, it doesn't find the twig file even I remove the .twig in the extends

Comment: post your file code

Comment: already updated, kindly check it out

Comment: come to chat discuss there

Answer (score 0):

TwigBridge interprets dot notation as directory paths and looks for the template relative to the views directory. I'm not sure if there's a way to use additional periods in your filename but would suggest the quick fix here is to remove that so TwigBridge doesn't get confused.

You also don't need the ../ directory traversal - you just need to specify the path relative to the views directory.

So I'd suggest changing it like this:

1. Rename the base file to **base-index.twig**
2. Change your extends directive to be like this: `{% extends layouts.base-index %}`